# Press buttons without release finger from screen

Tags: java, android, button

I want to press buttons like it shown on this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1NW3.jpg. That is I want to press buttons by holding finger on the screen and moving it along buttons. For example on this pic buttons 1, 2,5,8,9 will be pressed after this procedure.
Sorry for my bad english, but i cant to describe this in a different way.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry for not providing the very simple answer like "use the function xyz()" for this, but I think there are some general ways to do it:

1. You can create pictures that look like buttons (or bubbles or anything else appropriate), place them in an order that you need and then, getting each coordinate of the pointer (of the finger) on the screen, just check if this pointer gets into some area (maybe rectangle) inside each button. This logical area should be smaller than shown picture to let user move finger not so careful.
2. Another "solution" would be to put some "jitter" and send "left click" message on each position update along the way. In this case buttons should have some protection from multiple clicks. I remember on stackoverflow.com some advice how to do this: just disable the button on the click event.

Sorry if Android has some solution "out of the box", which I have no idea about, but the described problem seems to be general, not platform-specific.

Comment: Thanks, but however I suppose that Android has "out of the box".. I saw many apps in which it was realised..